# Multiple definition of ‘__udivdi3’ when linking ippcore in ndk project

Tags: android-ndk

When I compiled my ndk project and linked with the ipp static library **libippcore_l.a**, linker complains it met a multiple definitions error for this symbol **__udivdi3**. It seems it is a division function defined both in gcc library and ippcore library.

How can I get a rid of this link error? Removing the ippcore is unlikely a option.

```
..../Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle_r15c/build//../toolchains/x86-4.9/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/lib/gcc/i686-linux-android/4.9.x/../../../../i686-linux-android/bin\ld: error: 
 ..../_lib/Android/x86/libippcore_l.a(divdi3.o): multiple definition of '__udivdi3'

..../Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle_r15c/build//../toolchains/x86-4.9/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/lib/gcc/i686-linux-android/4.9.x/../../../../i686-linux-android/bin\ld:
..../Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle_r15c/build//../toolchains/x86-4.9/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/lib/gcc/i686-linux-android/4.9.x/libgcc.a(_udivdi3.o): previous definition here

clang++.exe: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Compiling setting

- NDK: r15c
- TOOLCHAIN: clang
- APP_ABI: x86
- APP_STL: c++_static
- FLAGS: -frtti -fexceptions -O2 -finline-functions -Wno-narrowing --std=c++11

Comment: Sounds like a bug in IPP. Either that, or ipp_core is meant to *replace* libgcc, not complement it, in which case you'll need to use `-nodefaultlibs` and link system libraries explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

I found if I compile along with another a cpp file which using `<iostream>`, the **__udivdi3** multiple definition issue is gone.

The minimal cpp file is like the following

```
#include <iostream> void f(){ std::cout << ""; }
```

I guess the iostream usage causes the `libgcc.a` not linked in so no definition conflits. This may be a temporary workaround, but I am still searching a solution.

Dump the result of

- `i686-linux-android-readelf --symbols libgcc.a`
- `i686-linux-android-readelf --symbols libippcore_l.a`

File: .\libgcc.a(_udivdi3.o)

```
Symbol table '.symtab' contains 16 entries:
   Num:    Value  Size Type    Bind   Vis     Ndx Name
    ...    
    ...
    12: 00000000        0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT   15 
    13: 00000000        0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT   16 
    14: 00000000        0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT   14 
    15: 00000000   257 FUNC        GLOBAL DEFAULT        1 __udivdi3
```

File: .\libippcore_l.a(divdi3.o)

```
Symbol table '.symtab' contains 45 entries:
   Num:    Value  Size Type    Bind   Vis     Ndx Name
    ...
    ...
    39: 000002a6        0 NOTYPE  LOCAL  DEFAULT        1 Lneed_decgas_3
    40: 00000273        0 NOTYPE  LOCAL  DEFAULT        1 Lafter_decgas_3
    41: 00000297        0 NOTYPE  LOCAL  DEFAULT        1 Lch_signgas_3
    42: 00000000   224 FUNC        GLOBAL DEFAULT        1 __divdi3
    43: 000000e0   162 FUNC        GLOBAL DEFAULT        1 __udivdi3
    44: 00000182   297 FUNC        GLOBAL DEFAULT        1 __moddi3
```